# I cannot importing KERAS tuner using anaconda

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I am trying to import Keras tuner using anaconda and I think it has some issue with its installation because when I am executing the code it keeps telling me that there is no such a model with this name, and I tried with many other names but not worked, then I noticed that there is some kind of warnings in the installation but not understand it as shown below
when I did each one of these commands

`pip install keras-tuner`
`pip install kerastuner`
`pip install keras_tuner`

the response was:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-tuner in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from keras-tuner) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from keras-tuner) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from keras-tuner) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kt-legacy in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from keras-tuner) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from keras-tuner) (7.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from keras-tuner) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from keras-tuner) (21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from ipython->keras-tuner) (0.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from ipython->keras-tuner) (3.0.18)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from ipython->keras-tuner) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from ipython->keras-tuner) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from ipython->keras-tuner) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from ipython->keras-tuner) (5.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from ipython->keras-tuner) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from ipython->keras-tuner) (5.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from ipython->keras-tuner) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython->keras-tuner) (0.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython->keras-tuner) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython->keras-tuner) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from packaging->keras-tuner) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from requests->keras-tuner) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from requests->keras-tuner) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from requests->keras-tuner) (3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from requests->keras-tuner) (1.26.6)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (0.37.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (1.35.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.4 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.24.3 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (1.39.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (3.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.0 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (3.15.6)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (0.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-data-server<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard->keras-tuner) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from absl-py>=0.4->tensorboard->keras-tuner) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard->keras-tuner) (4.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard->keras-tuner) (4.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard->keras-tuner) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard->keras-tuner) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard->keras-tuner) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard->keras-tuner) (3.1.1)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\aapython3.9\lib\site-packages)
```

then when I am executing my code I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ExpMnistTunerE1.py", line 23, in
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kerastuner'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09ArP.png)

Comment: You wrote ```kerastuner```, does ```import keras_tuner as kt``` work?

Comment: As a side note: try not to mix ```pip``` and ```conda``` when installing new packages. It might work out fine for now, but one day the installation will break due to package inconsistencies

Comment: yes I tried the different combinations of the two words as I saw them with different codes online, all of them had the same error.